# How can I read system information in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

Following from this [OS-agnostic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466684/how-can-i-return-system-information-in-python), specifically [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466684/how-can-i-return-system-information-in-python#467291), similar to data available from the likes of /proc/meminfo on Linux, how can I read system information from Windows using Python (including, but not limited to memory usage).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar question asked:

[How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

There are quite a few answers telling you how to accomplish this in windows.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows, if you want to get info like from the SYSTEMINFO command, you can use the [WMI module.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/)

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()    
systeminfo = c.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]

Manufacturer = systeminfo.Manufacturer
Model = systeminfo.Model
```

...

similarly, the os-related info could be got from `osinfo = c.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0]`
the full list of [system info is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [os info is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the systeminfo.exe wrapper I created a while back, it's a bit unorthodox but it seems to do the trick easily enough and without much code.

This should work on 2000/XP/2003 Server, and should work on Vista and Win7 provided they come with systeminfo.exe and it is located on the path.

```
import os, re

def SysInfo():
    values  = {}
    cache   = os.popen2("SYSTEMINFO")
    source  = cache[1].read()
    sysOpts = ["Host Name", "OS Name", "OS Version", "Product ID", "System Manufacturer", "System Model", "System type", "BIOS Version", "Domain", "Windows Directory", "Total Physical Memory", "Available Physical Memory", "Logon Server"]

    for opt in sysOpts:
        values[opt] = [item.strip() for item in re.findall("%s:\w*(.*?)\n" % (opt), source, re.IGNORECASE)][0]
    return values
```

You can easily append the rest of the data fields to the sysOpts variable, excluding those that provide multiple lines for their results, like CPU & NIC information. A simple mod to the regexp line should be able to handle that.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Some answers given can make trouble if the OS language is not native English. I searched for a way to get a wrapper around the `systeminfo.exe` and found the following solution. To make it more comfortable I pack the result in a dictionary:

```
import os
import tempfile

def get_system_info_dict():

    tmp_dir=tempfile.gettempdir()
    file_path=os.path.join(tmp_dir,'out')
    # Call the system command that delivers the needed information
    os.system('powershell -Command gcim WIN32_ComputerSystem -Property * >%s'%file_path)

    with open(file_path,'r') as fh:
        data=fh.read()
    os.remove(file_path)

    data_dict={}
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        try:
            k,v=line.split(':')
        except ValueError:
            continue
        k = k.strip(' ')
        v = v.strip(' ')
        if v!='':
            data_dict[k]=v

    return data_dict
```

Each key of a the resulting dictionary is a property (in English!) and the related value is the data stored for the property.