# Get system information(CPU speed-Total RAM-Graphic Card model etc.) under Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.4, system-information

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful. Is this possible to get system information like;

```
CPU: Intel Core i7-3770K CPU @3.5Ghz
RAM: 8GB
Graphic Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680
```

under Windows? How can I reach this output?

Edit: `platform.processor()` is not giving the output that I want. So that is useless for me.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but in case no one has one -- [Discussion on this topic](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/300786/how-to-get-graphics-card-details-in-python) has a post near the bottom with some sample code for use of dbus on linux. [This git repo](http://repo.or.cz/w/dbus4win.git/blob/HEAD:/README.win) has info about setting up dbus for windows. Maybe combine the two with some elbow grease and you might be on to something

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've been wondering how to do this myself for a while now, so I dug around a bit and came up with this solution using `wmi` (which requires `pywin32`). **Of course, it goes without saying, this only works on Windows machines (and the question has the `Windows` tag).**

```
import wmi

computer = wmi.WMI()
computer_info = computer.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]
os_info = computer.Win32_OperatingSystem()[0]
proc_info = computer.Win32_Processor()[0]
gpu_info = computer.Win32_VideoController()[0]

os_name = os_info.Name.encode('utf-8').split(b'|')[0]
os_version = ' '.join([os_info.Version, os_info.BuildNumber])
system_ram = float(os_info.TotalVisibleMemorySize) / 1048576  # KB to GB

print('OS Name: {0}'.format(os_name))
print('OS Version: {0}'.format(os_version))
print('CPU: {0}'.format(proc_info.Name))
print('RAM: {0} GB'.format(system_ram))
print('Graphics Card: {0}'.format(gpu_info.Name))
```

Output example:

```
OS Name: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 
OS Version: 6.1.7601 7601
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
RAM: 15.9443855286 GB
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
```

You can install both required packages via `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade wmi
pip install --upgrade pypiwin32
```

To see what other variables you can access in various Win32 controller classes, take a look at this documentation:

- [Win32_ComputerSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Win32_Processor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Win32_VideoController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512(v=vs.85).aspx)

Related answer found on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11785020/295246

---

**Update:** For System RAM, you can use either `os_info.TotalVisibleMemorySize` (returns the value in kilobytes) or `computer_info.TotalPhysicalMemory` (returns the value in bytes). If you use the latter, you can use `hurry.filesize` to quickly convert it to a pretty human readable string.

For example:

```
from hurry.filesize import size
...
size(int(computer_info.TotalPhysicalMemory))
```

Which in my case outputs: `15G`
You can even modify the G to whatever else you want. See this SO answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194348/295246

Comment: Well it's ok at least I got ram and cpu as I wanted. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Nels Carlson see, this is how to give a correct answer.

Comment: @GLHF GPU information is there also. Did I miss something in your question?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I missed that. This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you again.