# Translating Python 2 code to Python 3, can't seem to split

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have run into a problem while trying some code [I found here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38105273):

```
os_name = os_info.Name.encode('utf-8').split('|')[0]
```

Error:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I found out that there could be problem that I use Python 3, and not Python 2.

Comment: Where did you get `os_info` from?

Comment: @MrJLP: the error is pretty clear here, and is reproducible with any bytes value and `split()`.

Comment: Maybe try explaining the problem you're trying to solve, and then explain that you believe that code solves it in python 2 and work towards a solution in python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encoded your string to a bytes object, but then tried to split it with a string object. `bytes.split()` only takes a bytes value:

```
os_name = os_info.Name.encode('utf-8').split(b'|')[0]
```

The answer you found was actually meant to work on Python 3; I've edited to correct the mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick someone made me confused like this os_name = os_info.Name.encode(b'utf-8').split('|')[0]