# Get system free memory in python

Tags: python, memory, operating-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get current CPU and RAM usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python)

Is there a way to get the free memory of the system, using python?
`os` and `sys` don't seem to expose this sort of functionality.

Obviously, one could use `subprocess` or `os.system`, but it wouldn't be portable, nor reliable without serious testing.

Comment: AFAIK it's not in the standard library, so you'll need to code a platform-specific version for each platform, or use a third-party module.

Comment: I think a useful starting point would be to define what precisely you mean by "free memory".

Comment: I think this thread might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204378/getting-total-free-ram-from-within-python

Comment: Take a look at the psutil library.  It is mentioned (with links) in the duplicate questions found by @bhamby.

Comment: Indeed, it's a duplicate, sorry about that

Comment: @NPE not counting buffers, if that's what you mean