# Getting system status in python

Tags: python, operating-system

Is there any way to get system status in python, for example the amount of memory free, processes that are running, cpu load and so on.
I know on linux I can get this from the /proc directory, but I would like to do this on unix and windows as well.

Comment: Duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276052/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466684/how-can-i-return-system-information-in-python/467291

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any such library/ package that currently supports both Linux and Windows. There's [libstatgrab](http://www.i-scream.org/libstatgrab/) which doesn't seem to be very actively developed (it already supports a decent variety of Unix platforms though) and the very active [PSI (Python System Information)](http://bitbucket.org/chrismiles/psi/wiki/Home) which works on AIX, Linux, SunOS and Darwin. Both projects aim at having Windows support sometime in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a cross-platform library for that yet (there definitely should be one though)

I can however provide you with one snippet I used to get the current CPU load from `/proc/stat` under Linux:

**Edit**: replaced horrible undocumented code with slightly more pythonic and documented code

```
import time

INTERVAL = 0.1

def getTimeList():
    """
    Fetches a list of time units the cpu has spent in various modes
    Detailed explanation at http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm
    """
    cpuStats = file("/proc/stat", "r").readline()
    columns = cpuStats.replace("cpu", "").split(" ")
    return map(int, filter(None, columns))

def deltaTime(interval):
    """
    Returns the difference of the cpu statistics returned by getTimeList
    that occurred in the given time delta
    """
    timeList1 = getTimeList()
    time.sleep(interval)
    timeList2 = getTimeList()
    return [(t2-t1) for t1, t2 in zip(timeList1, timeList2)]

def getCpuLoad():
    """
    Returns the cpu load as a value from the interval [0.0, 1.0]
    """
    dt = list(deltaTime(INTERVAL))
    idle_time = float(dt[3])
    total_time = sum(dt)
    load = 1-(idle_time/total_time)
    return load


while True:
    print "CPU usage=%.2f%%" % (getCpuLoad()*100.0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```