# Since information of the hardware sees installed in python?

Tags: python, hardware, platform, processor

Can I know this information across python?, for example, the name of the card graphic, processor, audio, mother board ....

Comment: It depends, what platform are you programming for?

Comment: You can only take informations the system give you.

Comment: please clarify the title of your question. I cannot understand what it says.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything in Python itself. You can detect what OS you're on via the platform module. Otherwise

See also:

- [How can I return system information in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466684/how-can-i-return-system-information-in-python)

If you're on Windows, you can probably use PyWin32 to get some of this information. See the following recipe to get an idea of some of the stuff you can get:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511491-getting-system-information-under-windows/

I also wrote a little about this regarding getting Windows system information here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/01/27/getting-windows-system-information-with-python/

You might be able to use HAL:

- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/300786/how-to-get-graphics-card-details-in-python

I have also found the [psutil project](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) very helpful. I also came across [PyCPU](http://screeniqsys.com/blog/2012/11/07/pycpu-a-python-library-for-cpu-information/), although I'm unsure what its status is.

For Linux (and probably Mac), you'll probably have to use system commands called via Python's subprocess module and parse the result(s).

Comment: For Linux, lspci and dmidecode are good at retrieving lots of information.

Comment: Thanks, I see it is difficult sabar specific hardware with python.